# Android threads don't work properly in background mode

Tags: android, multithreading, android-vibration

I'm trying to make a metronome. It has sound and vibro. The `Service` start metronome, and after starting the sound the vibro are synchronical, but  when I click `home button`, turning metronome to the background mode, sound and vibro don't work to the beat (vibration pauses for a while).

```
 public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    bpm = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.BPM, 60);
    vibrator = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    Thread sound = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                metronome.setBeat(Constants.BEATS);
                metronome.setNoteValue(Constants.NOTE_VALUE);
                metronome.setBpm(bpm);
                metronome.setBeatSound(Constants.BEAT_SOUND);
                metronome.setSound(Constants.SOUND);

                try {
                    metronome.play();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });
    Thread vibro = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                long pattern[] = new long[3];
                pattern[0] = 0;
                pattern[1] = 50;
                pattern[2] = 950;
                vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
        }
    });
    sound.start();
    vibro.start();
```

how  to  synchronize them?

P.S. Also my vibrations stop if I lock the screen (but sound is continuing).

---

**EDIT**

I tried to use `CyclicBarrier` and found, that problem  wasn't in a thread. Problem exists, because of "native" vibrations, that  `home button` has. So, as I understand, these vibration make a queue and therefore my metronome vibro looses the tempo.

What can I do? I've made the  restarting of the metronome `Service`  at the `onStart` and `onStop`  method,  but it'  clumsy  and  it doesn't  solve  the problem, when I  click `menu-button`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I know of to synchronize multiple threads is to use a [CyclicBarrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). The idea is that after doing his part each threads call `await()` and is blocked until the last one arrives, at which point they are all released at once.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It didn't  help. I changed my post.